# ggplot2 facet_wrap with two nested variables: use different strip.position/switch for each variable?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap, facet-grid

I am making a `ggplot` where I use `facet_wrap` with two variables, say first `var_1` with values A/B, second `var_2` with 1/2, resulting into four facets, A-1, A-2, B-1, B-2. I would want the `var_1` A/B title to show on top, and the `var_2` 1/2 to show up on the side. 
Doing this with `facet_wrap(~dim_1 +dim_2, ncol=1)`, it seems however the argument `strip.position` will apply the same position for both? Another approach could be to use `facet_grid()` (which does want I want, to have facets both horizontal and vertical) but does not allow to set the number of rows/columns!?

Code below, with actual output, and what I want to have!

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(dim_1 = rep(c("A", "B"), each=4),
                 dim_2 = rep(c("1", "2"), times=4),
                 x = rnorm(8), y = rnorm(8))

p <- ggplot(aes(x=x, y=y), data=df) +
  geom_point()


p+
  facet_wrap(~dim_1 +dim_2, ncol=1, strip.position = c("left"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-09-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I don't think this is possible within ggplot, but you could make two charts with the A and B headers and use something like `patchwork` or `cowplot` to combine them afterwards.

Comment: @Parfait what I mean is that `facet_grid` would plot over two columns (A and B), can't restrict to have only one column

Comment: @Matifou You can create two separate plots with different values of `dim1` using `facet_grid` to get the facet labels in desired positions, & stack them into a single column, using `patchwork` / `cowplot` / etc. as suggested above. I'll admit I don't really see the point in presenting plots this way, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know a way to accomplish that within ggplot itself, but another approach would be to combine two plots using `patchwork`:

```
library(patchwork)
myplot <- function(section = "A") {
  ggplot(subset(df, df$dim_1 == section), aes(x,y)) + 
    geom_point() +
    # coord_cartesian(xlim = c(min(df$x), max(df$x))) +   # To get single x scale between all plots
    facet_grid(dim_2~dim_1, switch = "y") 
}
myplot("A") / myplot("B")
```

[image]